# How to get mvc pipeline to authenticate oidc in .net core 5

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core-mvc, openid-connect, asp.net-core-5.0

i'm trying to figure out a way to get mvc to authenticate AzureAD oidc token. My application is backend only, no sign in or sign out. so I want to get user claims from `OnAuthorizationAsync(**AuthorizationFilterContext** context)`, but it always return empty in httpcontext. I would think it might be some sort of configuration issue in `AddOpenIdConnect`. The following is my settings in `ConfigureServices`. What need to be done for more to get the user claims?

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
        //    options =>
        //{
        //    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        //    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; //AuthorizationConstants.AuthenticationSchemes.Oidc
        //} //behave the same with or without this setting
        )
        .AddOpenIdConnect("oidc", options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = azureAdConfig.ClientId;
            options.ConfigurationManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(azureAdConfig.EntryUrl, new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever());
        });



 Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        // routing and other things
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();
    }
```

Comment: Hi @briswill, please firstly check your token if it contains the claims. You can encode the token in [this website](https://jwt.io/).

Comment: Hey @Rena, we used Microsoft AzureAd login token, it contains the user name and user email information in the token. I think it contains the valid claims.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have does not work at all. OpenIDConnect only handles the authentication part, but the received tokens are just lost in your setup. The second problem you have is that you don't mix JwtBearer with AddOpenIdConnect. JwtBearer is for the API that receives access tokens from the client.

A proper skeleton for what you need to configure is:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddCookie(opt =>
{
}).AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
});
```

You should combine the OpenIDConnectHandler with the Cookie handler. Then it will work.

See this article for more details:
[How do I implement Blazor authentication with OpenID Connect?](https://www.syncfusion.com/faq/blazo/general/how-do-i-implement-blazor-authentication-with-openid-connect)

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail
about this topic: [Debugging OpenID Connect claim problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/03/28/missing-openid-connect-claims-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: Thanks for the information. I have tried the suggestion the solution. We are using AzureAd for authentication. And there are "name" and "preferred_username" in the token as well with other claims like "iss", "aud", "scp", etc. Not sure what else need to be setup in those options.

Comment: What is your question about the claims?

Comment: if you are using AzureAd,, then I would recomend that you take a look at the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/microsoft-identity-web library, that you can see as a superset of AddCookie/AddOpenIdConnect that will handle a lot of the magic for you.

Comment: Thanks Tore, I have tried it out Microsoft.Identity.Web; and it does work like magic. thanks for the comments services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(config, "AzureAd");